# Find clustering/partitioning based on edge weight

Tags: graphs, clustering

So I have a complete digraph with non-zero positive edge weights. The nodes represent locations and edge weights are the travel times between the two corresponding nodes. I have 2 or more agents traversing the graph. The goal is that they visit as many nodes as possible within a certain amount of time. I have the following initial solution to the problem:

Assume two agents, A0  and A1. We start with a list, L, of all nodes. A0 picks the node from L that is closest to itself and removes it from L. Let's call this node X and the travel time (from A0 to X) t0. Then A1 gets to pick the closest node from the remaining nodes in L. After t0 time has passed, A0 picks the node from L which is closest to X and once again removes it from L. This goes on until either all nodes have been visited or after a certain total amount of time has passed.

This is basically a Greedy solution. However, I know I can do better than this since the agents will be in each others way constantly. Therefore, I decided my next, improved, attempt will involve clustering the graph into K subgraphs. Here, K is the amount of agents.

But what is the best clustering? I thought about K-means clustering, but this gives no guarantee about the amount of nodes in each cluster, it only accounts for the amount of variance within each cluster. This may result in unequal cluster sizes. This is a problem when one ore more agents have visited all the nodes in their respective clusters but there are many remaining unvisited nodes in the graph. This would not be a very efficient solution.

Therefore I thought of the following solution. I can add up all the edge weights in a specific cluster, call this number W. Now, if I find an algorithm that generates clusters with similar values of W, this would yield a much more efficient solution. Or at least I like to think so.

Few questions. Is there such an algorithm? Or are there better solutions to my problem that I don't yet know about.